# Unbound Prefix Error in AXML

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a problem on my axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/optionLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/start" />

    (X) <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andorid:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mon, 13:30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andorid:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/end" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andorid:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mon, 14:30" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

On the (X) marked position I got a unbound prefix error (if I delete this textView the error is marked on the next TextView). The first TextView is working. All the others don't. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of :

```
andorid:textColor="@color/black"
```

write:

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
```

You wrote `android` wrong.